# How to find derivatives in the following table?

Tags: calculus

Ive tried looking for a similar question on the forums but I couldn't find any. I would greatly appreciate any help given!

[image]

Comment: You can use the chain rule to better define $f'(x)$ and $w'(x)$

Answer (score 2):

There is something called [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). In your case $f(x)=g(h(x))$. So $f'(x)=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)$.

Therefore $f'(3)=g'(h(1))h'(1)=g(3)\times (-0.5)=2\times(-0.5)=-1$.
 Do the other one yourself.